# SQL - How do I create a dynamic query that references values?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-iq

I would like to make it easier to update multiple SQL queries and change the table names for each query in one go.

For example, is it possible for me to just update the first line here and for the queries below to run against that table name?

I am using Sybase IQ.

Thanks

tablename1='tablename';

alter table tablename1
add visit_time_latest varchar(255) default null;

update tablename1
set visit_time_latest = replace (visit_time,'_',':');

update tablename1 
set visit_time_latest = replace (visit_time_latest,' ','');

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the variable to build dynamic queries that you can run via execute(), eg:

```
declare @tablename1 varchar(100), @query varchar(1000)
select  @tablename1 = 'tablename'
select  @query='alter table '+@tablename1+' add visit_time_latest varchar(255) not null'
execute(@query)
```